# How to control the order of servers listed in the SSMS connection dialog?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, tools

My current project involves a lot of database shuffling as we upgrade from SQL 2008 -> 2012, re-task hardware, repeat.

One minor annoyance is the connection dialog in SSMS re-shuffling the server order to put the most recent on top.  Given that on any particular day I'm connecting to 6-10 DB servers and want to quickly find a specific one in the list, this behavior is much more of a hindrance than a help.

Is there a way to disable this behavior, having the servers listed alphabetically, or in the order they were added...or *anything* that doesn't change every time I connect to a server?

Barring that, is there an *entirely different* way to better manage connecting to a specific server from a list/farm of them?

I'm using SSMS for SQL 2012 (though I'm curious about 2008 solutions as well).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Registered Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188231.aspx) or set up a [Central Management Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895144.aspx) (CMS). I recommend the latter if you can take the (small) time to set up the infrastructure because it will allow everyone to see the same list of servers, instead of just you (Registered Servers are stored in the registry). The only "drawback" with a CMS is that you have to use Windows Authentication because passwords aren't persisted to disk.

Both these features allow you to maintain an ordered/grouped list of servers, and manage servers as groups. This is very powerful because Policy-Based Management is tightly integrated with the GUI.

This works with all server versions -- I run SSMS 2012 and manage 2005-2012 servers. A CMS server can be set up on an Express edition, so licencing isn't a concern; however, I do recommend taking system database backups so the server list is recoverable.

Comment: The only drawback we ran into with this before was (correct me if I'm wrong) the CMS can't be a member of its own group...so you need an extra instance *just* to be a CMS, correct?  How do you get around this/make it useful?...or do you just eat having an extra instance somewhere?  One more item: most of us work remotely, not always connected to the domain, how would this behave when launching SSMS for local development, lag, no impact?

Comment: @Nick: Yes, I recommend setting up a new instance just for the CMS. This way it's separated from the actual SQL infrastructure. That's why I touched on licencing in my answer, and noted it would take a small amount of extra effort to set up.

Comment: @Nick: I'd need to know more about the infrastruture set up -- something is not making sense. You don't connect directly from your home machine to the production SQL servers, do you (I'm assuming not)? If you need to include local servers, use Registered Servers for that part because the list is stored locally.

Comment: Oh yes we do :) This is my dev machine, so I'm connected to all SQL servers in the SE infrastructure from here (but sometimes not, doing local dev and not on the VPN...especially on the laptop).  Licensing isn't a major issue, but the totally separate instance (and where to keep it) are a bit of an unknown...not sure which server we'd shove that on.  My concern is when SSMS can't reach the CMS, is there some sort of timeout when you open SSMS?

Comment: @Nick: Yeah, it's much easier when everything is virtualized. :) We keep ours on a management VM. Another option is to use a Developer edition instance instead of Express, which gives you SQL Agent to tell you if something blows up. No, there's no timeout when opening SSMS. You only get a wait when you try to expand the CMS node in the Registered Servers tab (to be expected).

Comment: We're going to look at a CMS setup for everyone given that Express is an option (wasn't aware of that last time we looked at it)...but for now Registered servers in a window docked beneath object explorer works wonderfully, thanks!

Comment: @Nick: You're welcome! A couple other thoughts: use a Developer edition (tiny cost) instance instead of Express so you get SQL Agent; it may be useful to use a combination of CMS (for shared servers) and Registered Servers (for local servers on your box).

Answer (score 4):

You can't control this order unless you hack into SqlStudio.bin, or remove entries and re-add them in the order you want. Workarounds include:

- You can delete individual entries manually (it's not intuitive - press the delete key for the highlighted item in the dropdown) - see this SQL Server blog post: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160216044501/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/managingsql/archive/2011/07/13/deleting-old-server-names-from-quot-connect-to-server-quot-dialog-in-ssms.aspx)
- Just deleting the SqlStudio.bin file entirely (when SSMS is closed). When you restart SSMS, the MRU list will be empty, since a new bin file will be created.
- You can use a script like this one: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/94e5c3ca-c76d-48d0-ad96-8348883e8db8/
- You can use a custom-built UI like this one (note that I have not tested this): http://www.walkersretreat.co.nz/files/SSMSMRU.zip
- I've blogged about this problem as well:
  https://sqlblog.org/2009/03/18/managing-the-mru-list-for-the-connect-to-server-dialog-in-ssms

Note that the order will get messed up as soon as you connect to a server that's not in the first position, since it really is an MRU list (where the most recent connection is listed first).

You can see more details in these SO questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230159/how-to-delete-server-entries-in-sql-server-management-studios-connect-to-serve
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059105/how-to-remove-server-name-items-from-history-of-sql-server-management-studio

And you can see the bug that I filed that initiated the ability to use the delete key:

- http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=424800

And other bugs that have sprung up as a result:

- http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/564834/ssms-change-connection-dialog-should-offer-registered-servers
- http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/683641/ssms-add-tooltip-to-connect-to-server-mru-entries
- http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/542304
- http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/624073/connect-to-server-screen-has-duplicate-instance-names-in-server-name-list

Comment: +1. I didn't know you could hit del with a mouse over in SSMS. That is worth it's weight in gold.

Answer (score 1):

You actually do not need to hack anything, as far as I have solved this problem in my SSMS Add-in SSMSBoost (.com) - you can download it and use for free.
You simply define a list of your preferred connections in settings (see picture) and then this will be available as drop-down on toolbar, so even switching between servers takes only one click, as you you would switch between databases in native database-list drop down.

Now some pictures:

Settings Dialogue:
[image]

If you look at other options you will also find "Important DB alert" - this one might be useful for you, as far as you switch between new and old DBs, test and real server during work on your project. You can configure Alert, that will be displayed as BIG Tooltip at specified position at the screen as far as you connect to "important" database, so you will notice that you are working on REAL or Test environment.

Next picture shows contents of toolbar drop-down, where you see your preferred connections listed above, and below all databases from current server (same list as in native databases list drop-down)

[image]

As far as I work permanently on improvements you are welcome to write me your proposals, so that we will make add-in even more better.

Comment: Thanks for following me on Twitter -- I only registered that account to lock up the name, though. That said, I'm in the process of setting up a blog which will have a dedicated Twitter account, and you can follow that if you'd like when it's released (I'll message you here with the details). Thanks.

Comment: As promised, http://twitter.com/VoluntaryDBA