# Managing Sql Server 2012 Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have some questions about Sql Server 2012 Standard Edition.

1. Does anyone know of 3rd party software to manage Sql Server 2012 Standard Edition with?
2. Is it advisable to use SSMS 2005/2008 Express to manage a SQL Server 2012?

The reason I ask is that we only have XP workstations and SSMS 2012 requires Vista/Windows 7 or above.

Thank you, Pieter

Comment: Using a previous version of SSMS will not allow you take advantage of new features using the GUI. See the answer to this question for an alternative solution: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22931/connecting-to-a-remote-sql-server-2008-instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use remote desktop to connect to the server where 2012 is installed, then run the tools from there.

Comment: Yes. I think in the end that is going to be the easiest solution.